# strip international calling code from phone number using php

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have php mysql application and i want the phone numbers be saved in a specific format. after some googling i reached up to this function:

```
function RemoveExt($phone) {
    if(substr($phone,0,1) == '+' || substr($phone, 0,2) == 00){
        $phone = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $phone);
        }

    $phone=trim($phone);
    $prefixs=array('0097150','0097156','0097152','0097155', '97150','97156','97155','97152','050','056','055','052','00');

    $replace=array('050','056','052','055','050','056','055','052','050','056','055','052','00');
      $count = count($prefixs); 
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if(strncmp($phone, $prefixs[$i], strlen($prefixs[$i])) == 0){

            $phone = preg_replace('/^'.$prefixs[$i].'/i','',$phone);
             $ext=$replace[$i];
            return array('phone' => $phone, 'ext' => $ext);
        }else{
        return array('phone' => $phone, 'ext' => $ext); 
        } 
    }
}
```

for example the phone number +971501234567  => 
"+" will be the international code, 
"971" will be the country code, 
"50"  will be the mobile network code and 
"1234567" will be the mobile number.

noted that we have more than one mobile code. 
The question that I need to save two parts from the number (mobile network code, mobile number)
for example: +971501234567   will be saved as (050) the mobile network code   and (1234567) the mobile number.

could anyone help me to achive that?.

Comment: So you won't allow international numbers at all? This sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: you can use the native php function substr() to achieve what you want pretty easily.

Comment: not every countrycode has the same length.. so substr wouldn't do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to share the working class :-

```
    function RemoveExt($phone) {

    if(substr($phone,0,1) == '+'){
        $phone = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '00', $phone);
        }

    $prefix=array('0097150','0097156','0097155','0097152','97150','97156','97155','97152','050','056','055','052','00');

    $replace=array('050','056','055','052','050','056','055','052','050','056','055','052','00');
      $count =count($prefix);
      $counter=0;
      while( $counter < $count){
            if(strncmp($phone, $prefix[$counter] , strlen($prefix[$counter])) == 0){

                $phone=substr($phone, strlen($prefix[$counter]));
                $ext=$replace[$counter];

            }
            $counter++;
        }
        return array('phone' => $phone, 'ext' => $ext);
}
```

Hope help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If they always take the form of +971501234567 just chop off the last 9 numbers. From these, take the last seven as the mobile number, prepend the first two with a 0 as the mobile network.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. after posting I solve it by my self.

Comment: I am trying to correct user entry mistakes. every user enter value by his own so I need to unify values in my database table